# Icon resized in Chrome extension permissions dialog

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I've made a chrome extension with 128x128, 48x48, and 16x16 icons (in px).

Per the instruction [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images#iconsize), I've left space around the large icon. Even so, when I open up chrome://extensions/ and then open the Permissions dialog for my extension, it is using the 128x128 image and scaling it down. It visibly looks worse for it.

Is this fixable? Is there something I can do to the 128x128 image? A manifest file change?

Comment: I was going to say that you can measure the displayed size and provide an extra icon for that size but that doesn't seem to be working. I tried with the dialog that pops up when you want to delete the extension. The icon is displayed at 64x64 pixels but it's using the 128x128 icon even after adding a 64x64 icon to the extension. Same with the permissions dialog though the displayed size is 69x69. Bummer.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Well, it isn't _just me_. And this only appears in the permissions dialog (and apparently the uninstall dialog), so the user probably won't see it often.